# Session variable lost on Sailsjs when redirected from third party (Paypal)

Tags: node.js, session, paypal, sails.js

Before I write my first question, I just want to thank this community for being awesome at helping all of us programmer in our daily work.

Here is my problem:
On my SailsJs application, I store session variable before I redirect to Paypal to keep the transaction information.
But when my users come back from Paypal, 30% of the time the session variable is lost.

As anyone had this problem before and how did you solve it?

For now, I am thinking to store the session variable in a database before redirecting to Paypal but I was wondering if there was another way to do it. 
Thanks!

Comment: Not a "node" dev. Based on above, sounds like you're using in-memory for persistence(?). So, aside from the obvious (session expiration), are you on some "server farm" (multiple servers)?